# Unexpected Token ERROR?

Tags: apex, error

[image]

Any thoughts on why the errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please copy and paste your code into your question and use the `{}` tool or Ctrl-K to format it appropriately as code. Screenshots are generally harder to work with.

In this case, you have two simple syntax errors:

```
public Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMapMethod {
```

This method declaration is missing its parameter list, which in this case is empty. You must include an empty parameter list `()` in any method declaration that doesn't take parameters, the only exception being a getter/setter on a property. Hence:

```
public Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMapMethod() {
```

The other issue is that your object creation syntax is wrong.

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>
```

Object constructors are method calls, and also require parentheses as such. Additionally, all statements in Apex end with a semicolon, as in most C/Java family languages.

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
```

#### However....

You don't have to do most of this code anyway, because Apex has a "magic" syntax for initializing sObject maps of Id to sObject. Just pass the SOQL-query list directly to the Map constructor:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, .... FROM Opportunity ...]);
```

Then you don't need a separate list or `for` loop at all, and your method becomes a one-liner:

```
return new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, .... FROM Opportunity ...]);
```

Comment: Given that you can reduce it to a 1 liner, I don't think you really need this method.

Answer (score 0):

These are the syntax issues basically:

```
1. Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

2. List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>([Select Id, name from Opportunity]);

3. public Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMapMethod(){

   }
```

Comment: (2) is actually not a mistake - there's no need to use the `List` constructor when assigning the results of a SOQL query.